# Wrong User reported by Context.User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asmx, basic-authentication

Folks,

I have an asmx web service on a server.  The application for the service uses HTTPS and basic authentication.  When it is called, and I am forced to log in with the domain, but "Context.User.Identity.Name" return the local user!

so

a login of

myDomain\myUserName

results in

Context.User.Identity.Name = "localMachineName\myUserName"

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Brett

Comment: Okay, I just found out that the server in not even in a domain, so, I guess the question is, how am I logging into a local account (myUserName) using a domain specifier (myDomainWhichDoesNotExist\myUserName)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the web.config setup to use windows authentication by chance? If so I believe it will give you the local user principal instead of the domain user you authenticated with.

The fix should be to change your web.config to use forms authentication.

Hope this helps.